# How do you define the vectors of a basis with respect to another basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's we're in vector space $E$ of dimension 3, and we have the basis $B_0 = (e1,e2,e3)$. I have another basis $B = (e1+e2, e1+e3, e2+e3)$. The problem asks me to give the coordinates of $e1,e2,e3$ "in the basis $B$". I'm not exactly sure what this means. I'm assuming this is what a "change of basis" is, but I'm not too sure.

I know that, if I create a matrix in which the column vectors are the vectors of $B$, then we have the "change of basis matrix", and right-multplying that matrix with a set of coordinates of a vector in basis $B$ with get me the coordinates in the canonical base, right? However, I'm not sure how to apply this knowledge to this particular problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$B = (e_1+e_2, e_1+e_3, e_2+e_3) = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$$

You need to write $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as linear combination of $u_1, u_2, u_3$

For example $e_1 = (1/2)(u_1+u_2-u_3)$, therefore, in $B$ we have  $e_1 = (1/2, 1/2, -1/2)$

Similarly for $e_2 $and $e_3 $ you find the components in new basis $B$.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Karmani Thanks for your answer. There's something I'm not sure about, however. So, we want to find $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a(e_1 + e_2) + b(e_1 + e_3) + c(e_2 + e_3) = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$, correct?

So this gives us $ae_1 + ae_2 + be_1 + be_3 + ce_2 + ce_3 = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$. From here, I don't know what to do; am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Let $ae_1 + ae_2 + be_1 + be_3 + ce_2 + ce_3 = e_1$ and find coefficients. Similarly for$ e_2$ and$ e_3.$

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates are just the coefficients of the linear combination. Just find out how to express $B_0$ with $B_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here the systematic way for basis transformations using the inverse of a matrix.

- The transformation matrix describing vectors in $B$ as vectors in $B_0$ **is given**:
  $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
- The transformation matrix describing vectors in $B_0$ as vectors in $B$ is the inverse $A^{-1}$:
  $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
  So, for example, if $B= (e1+e2, e1+e3, e2+e3) = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$, then
  $$e_1 = \frac{1}{2}(b_1+b_2-b_3) \mbox{ etc.}$$